# Is there any tool for inspecting a .Net assembly size?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, disassembly

I am looking for a tool that takes a .Net assembly as input and outputs each namespaces and classes ordered by size.

e.g.

```
    MyAssembly.dll 256Ko

    -> MyAssemby.MyNamespace 192Ko  
    --> MyAssemby.MyNamespace1.MyClass1 128Ko  
    --> MyAssemby.MyNamespace1.MyClass2 64Ko  
    -> MyAssemby.MyNamespace2 64Ko  
    --> MyAssemby.MyNamespace2.MyClass3 64Ko
```

Pretty much like WinDirStat does for directories.

Even better if it is free with a nice UI.

Comment: Seems to be a job for [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/).

Comment: What do you mean by size?  Are you measuring classes/members/actual size of bytes on disk/etc?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the hint Oliver.

Comment: @Jason, yes, I mean the actual bytes, once loaded in memory.